# mock systemtime when code is running in vm module

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I want to test some code that checks the current system time. The code in question is running inside of the [vm module](https://node.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/vm/#vmruninthiscontextcode-options). In the following test, I cannot mock the current system time using jest. I always get the current system time, instead of my mocked system time. How I can I make the vm module and jest play nicely together and make this test pass.

**myFunction.test.js**

```
const getDateUsingVM = require('./myFunction');
describe('getDateUsingVM', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.useFakeTimers();
  });
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.useRealTimers()
  });
  test('should return the same date as the mocked date', () => {
    const mockDate = new Date('2022-01-01T12:00:00Z');
    jest.setSystemTime(mockDate);
    const result = getDateUsingVM();
    expect(result).toBe(mockDate.toISOString());
  });
});
```

**myFunction.js**

```
const vm = require('vm');
function getDateUsingVM() {
  const script = `
    ((require) => {
      const currentDate = new Date();
      return currentDate.toISOString();
    })
  `;
  const theFunction = vm.runInThisContext(script);
  return theFunction(require);
}
module.exports = getDateUsingVM;
```

Answer (score 0):

Method 1 that works is using other methods in the VM module.

```js
const vm = require('vm');
function getDateUsingVM() {
  const script = `
    ((require) => {
      const currentDate = new Date();
      return currentDate.toISOString();
    })
    `;
    const vmScript = new vm.Script(script);
    const context = vm.createContext(global)
    return vmScript.runInContext(context)(require);
}
module.exports = getDateUsingVM;
```

Method 2 that works is using eval. gasp. the horrors.
The team is 100% in control of the code being evaled. This is a unit test. Eval in production with caution.

```js
const vm = require('vm');
function getDateUsingVM() {
  const script = `
    ((require) => {
      const currentDate = new Date();
      return currentDate.toISOString();
    })
    `;
    return eval(script)(require);
}
module.exports = getDateUsingVM; // not vm, it's using eval I would change name...
```